Zip a directory with subfolders and files without including parent directories in the zipped file
Before coming here, I've been looking for other topics and tested the provided answers and I'm still getting the same result.
So first of all, I have this folder structure.
uploads/
- student-records
-- John-Doe
--- files
---- Application 
---- Transcripts

I have to zip the directory files. The zip is working, just that it includes in the zipped the full path of the folder. Instead of the actual folder..
So I am getting this in my zip file laragon/mson/wp-content/uploads/student-records/John-Doe/files/... 
Here is my actual code
$student = $student_first_name .'-'. $student_last_name.'_'.$student_id;

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();  

$source = $upload_dir['basedir'] ."/student-records/" . $student . "/files/";

$zipFile = $upload_dir['path'] ."/student-records/" . $student . "/".$student.".zip";


// Initialize archive object
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

# Create a zip target
if( $zipArchive->open( $zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE ) !== TRUE ) {
    exit("Unable to open file.");
}           

// create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($sourceRelativePath, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);          

if (is_dir($sourceRelativePath)) {
    
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
        
        $filePath = str_replace( '\\', '/', $file->getRealPath() );
        
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            
            $zipArchive->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $filePath . '/'));
            
        } else if (is_file($file)) {
            $zipArchive->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $filePath), file_get_contents($filePath));
        }
    }
} else if (is_file($source)) {
    $zipArchive->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}

$zipArchive->close();

echo '<a href="'.$zipFileURL.'" target=""><span class="dashicons dashicons-download"></span> Download</a>';

}       


I need some help so it doesn't include in the zip file the full path and just the folder files along with its subfolders and files only.

I don't see where you define the value of $sourceRelativePath.

If you use ZipArchive::addFile you can add as a second argument the entry name, in your case you want the relative path.

@mmm, ops, I edited, that should $source

@Olivier, it's different, the other one only zips a whole folder and files under it. On this one, it includes subfolders. I already tried the solution on that one and it just gives the same output. The zipped file includes the parent directories.

You need to take another pass over this code, as it's full of undefined variables, and defined variables that are never used. You also need to verify that the the variables contain what you expect, and that the functions you're calling do what you expect and return what you expect.

Can't you just take a look at the value of the first argument of addFromString? I guess str_replace replaced nothing.

@JanBantolinay I just tested the linked answer, and it does include subfolders, and the paths are relative. The only issue I found is that (on Windows) it stores backslashes instead of forward slashes in entry names, but that's easy to fix.
